# Why is the entrypoints.json file not found?

Tags: configuration, webpack-encore, symfony6

This is my first time using Webpack-Encore, and I am trying to load the entrypoints.json file from a non-default location on my local machine. I am using the Symfony server and the document root of the web server is 'public_html' rather than 'public', but I have been unable to configure Symfony to look into the 'public_html' folder for the entrypoints.json file.

The error I receive is: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "...\SoCalOfficials-api/public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist."). However, the file does exist in "...\SoCalOfficials-api/public_html/build/entrypoints.json"

The Symfony server is started in the "...\SoCalOfficials-api" directory using the command:

symfony server:start --document-root=public_html

The framework.yaml file is as follows:

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public_html/build/manifest.json'
```

The webpack.config.php file is as follows:

```
Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public_html/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
```

The webpack successfully builds and writes files 5 files to 'public_html\build'.

Since the server's document root is 'public_html' I expected Symfony/Twig to look in that directory for the manifest.json file instead of 'public'.

All of the answers that I've found to this type of question were resolved by installing @symfony\webpack-encore and doing a build. However, this already works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem while deploying on shared hosting.

Turns out you have to change config in "config/packages/webpack_encore.yaml"

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

maybe also

```
webpack_encore:
    output_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public_html/build'
```

Now finally it's searching where it's supposed to!

Comment: It was the webpack_encore.yaml file that did it for me. The documentation didn't mention anything about that file. The documentation says that everything is configured in the webpack.config.js, but that is not completely the case. Thanks!